# Blocking Chinese IP addresses

Tags: ssh, brute-force, password-cracking

I recently checked one of my servers' `auth.log` file and noticed some very suspicious activity. I recently shut down my server's ssh daemon, so the logs end on Jan 22, but what I noticed after reviewing the log file was that all of the IP addresses are Chinese.

Here are the last 10 lines of failed login attempts:

```
$ cat auth.log | grep Failed | tail -n10
Jan 22 13:42:14 servername sshd[10306]: Failed password for root from 183.3.202.104 port 10894 ssh2
Jan 22 13:42:18 servername sshd[10306]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from 183.3.202.104 port 10894 ssh2]
Jan 22 13:42:28 servername sshd[10365]: Failed password for root from 183.3.202.104 port 34140 ssh2
Jan 22 13:42:32 servername sshd[10365]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from 183.3.202.104 port 34140 ssh2]
Jan 22 13:42:44 servername sshd[10423]: Failed password for root from 183.3.202.104 port 56290 ssh2
Jan 22 13:42:48 servername sshd[10423]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from 183.3.202.104 port 56290 ssh2]
Jan 22 13:43:03 servername sshd[10511]: Failed password for root from 183.3.202.104 port 64153 ssh2
Jan 22 13:43:08 servername sshd[10511]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from 183.3.202.104 port 64153 ssh2]
Jan 22 13:43:18 servername sshd[10569]: Failed password for root from 183.3.202.104 port 33472 ssh2
Jan 22 13:43:23 servername sshd[10569]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from 183.3.202.104 port 33472 ssh2]
```

When searching for non 183.3.202.104 IP addresses, the lines become:

```
$ cat auth.log | grep Failed | grep -v 183.3.202.104 | tail -n10
Jan 22 02:36:41 servername sshd[31074]: message repeated 5 times: [ Failed password for root from 221.203.142.71 port 33746 ssh2]
Jan 22 02:36:54 servername sshd[31388]: Failed password for root from 221.203.142.71 port 57792 ssh2
Jan 22 02:37:13 servername sshd[31388]: message repeated 5 times: [ Failed password for root from 221.203.142.71 port 57792 ssh2]
Jan 22 02:37:25 servername sshd[31698]: Failed password for root from 221.203.142.71 port 55440 ssh2
Jan 22 02:37:41 servername sshd[31698]: message repeated 5 times: [ Failed password for root from 221.203.142.71 port 55440 ssh2]
Jan 22 02:37:58 servername sshd[31918]: Failed password for root from 221.203.142.71 port 50225 ssh2
Jan 22 02:38:13 servername sshd[31918]: message repeated 5 times: [ Failed password for root from 221.203.142.71 port 50225 ssh2]
Jan 22 04:55:23 servername sshd[22179]: Failed password for invalid user support from 113.160.158.43 port 61614 ssh2
Jan 22 09:36:40 servername sshd[4160]: Failed password for invalid user a from 115.182.249.11 port 53046 ssh2
Jan 22 09:36:52 servername sshd[4204]: Failed password for invalid user oracle from 115.182.249.11 port 56673 ssh2
```

So first of all, I'd like to confirm that this is indeed an attack; I'm very unfamiliar with managing system security. Second, I'd like to know if there's any way to block all Chinese IP addresses; my server has so far been used solely in America and has nothing to do with China.

Comment: If they tried to log in as root, it's an attack.

Comment: Well that's good to know... All I need to do now is learn how to set up a firewall that works with changing IP addresses.

Comment: That might work. There are tools to block entire countries/regions. This will block simple attacks targeting low hanging fruit. However dedicated attacks will use Tor/VPN ect. to get around IP blocks.

Comment: A good search phrase is "geoip blocking" in whatever search engine you prefer. You may also want to look at "fail2ban".

Comment: To actively block ip's you might want to install [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which blocks ip's after x failed attempts.

Comment: @BadSkillz I like fail2ban. Good suggestion.

Comment: @PhilipRowlands An attempt to log in as root is not necessarily an attack. It might be the person just connected to the wrong host by accident. Of course in that case the person would also have to be clueless enough to type their root password over an ssh connection that had not successfully verified the host key. There is however a different reason to think it is an attack, and that is that there are many repeated failed passwords.

Comment: @AstroDan Rather than blocking IP addresses I think it is much better to disable password authentication on the ssh server (after setting up key authentication).

Comment: @kasperd Right, I agree. However Honesty asked about IP blocking and my response was far to short to be an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Devices with cryptic names and Chinese ip addresses connected to my router](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54930/devices-with-cryptic-names-and-chinese-ip-addresses-connected-to-my-router)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try [Wizcraft's block list](http://www.wizcrafts.net/chinese-iptables-blocklist.html), and format it accordingly. At the time of my post, this blocklist was last updated on Thursday, 24-Dec-2015 11:01:52 MST. Keep in mind, Taiwan is not part of Mainland China, but that Hong Kong now belongs to, and is controlled by Beijing.

If you only use your server in America exclusively, you could use *all* of those rules to block attackers. If not, edit out the ones you don't want, and keep the ones you do.

**Also keep in mind, this will not stop attackers from connecting to a VPN in a country of their choice, and once again attempting to login as root. This is merely a band-aid.**

**EDIT** - **BadSkillz** and **Jenny D** have recommended [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). This will probably be a better solution overall, but it probably wouldn't hurt to use both methods.

Comment: Want to add that geoIP datasets such as: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/ can help.

Answer (score 3):

I also find it disturbing to see these low brow brute force login attempts and sadly yes they are mostly from China ( 'Vacuum cleaner' espionage ) - Good news is the solution is simple - only permit login to your server using SSH keys which then enables you to disable passwords as a login method

First create your secure SSH keys :

see doc for linux/OSX/Windows  https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-gpg-key/

in a terminal on your local box issue

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "youremailaddr@example.com"
```

this will prompt you for a password (remember it) ... it will create a private and public key pair of files

```
private file  /home/mylogin/.ssh/id_rsa_supermoon
public file   /home/mylogin/.ssh/id_rsa_supermoon.pub
```

These files are now local to your machine ... just copy the public file onto your remote server and place into file (or append to)

```
/home/mylogin/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

assure it has proper file permissions on remote host

```
chmod 700 /home/mylogin/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/mylogin/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now back on your local host issue this to ssh login to your remote box

```
# only need to issue this set of 3 cmds once on same terminal
export REMOTE_IP=1.2.3.4 # your remote host IP
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_supermoon  # enter same password as above

ssh mylogin@${REMOTE_IP}
```

*** Start of Optional ------------ ***

PS - sick of password prompts on every ssh then put this into your local ~/.bashrc

```
if [ ! -S ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock ]; then
  eval $(ssh-agent)
  ln -sf "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
fi
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
ssh-add -l | grep "The agent has no identities" && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_supermoon
```

***------------ End of Optional***

IMPORTANT - confirm you can correctly login using ssh ... ONLY then on your remote host edit the ssh config file

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config  
# PasswordAuthentication yes   # we do NOT want yes if ssh keys work
PasswordAuthentication no
```

to engage above config file change on remote host just bounce ssh server :

```
sudo service sshd restart  # (systemd ONLY) this does not kill your login session
```

Done - You will immediately see no more such brute login attempts since your remote host now summarily ignores password attempts and those guttersnipes will crawl away to pester someone else's unprotected server